# How do I add markup for example program pages in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have a set of Doxygen-generated library documentation, complete with example programs.  They show up nicely under the "Examples" tab in the resultant documentation.  I would like to add some kind of Doxygen-type markup to these pages, but can't figure out how to do it.  All markup comments get removed and do not show up anywhere in the Doxygen output.  My hope is to include some descriptive paragraphs, and perhaps a set of program output that the user can look at. My workaround for the time being is to include all of this right in the source code as non-Doxygen comments.  This approach works, but it's not what I was hoping for.

```
/** 
 *  \brief ATTEMPTED DESCRIPTION
 *
 *  I would like to include some kind of markup on the example page for 
 *  this program.  I link to it just fine from one of my library routines,
 *  the the Doxygen-generated example page just shows all of this verbatim.
 *
 *  Is there any way to provide some kind of section where I can discuss
 *  the example program itself?  And potentially provide sample output
 *  and the like?  (I realize that doesn't make sense for "Hello World",
 *  but you get the idea.)
 */

#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the \snippet command?

Answer (score 0):

After exploring this issue over the course of the last month,
I've determined that you can't effectively change doxygen's output 
with markup inside of the example program file.

The solution is to build a separate page in your documentation,
include the example code with the `\include` directive, and then
provide links to this new example page manually.  For the example
above, create a file with the following format and use 
the `\include` directive to add the actual code from your example 
program.  It is then simple to add a narrative and a section for
program output.

In this example, create the file `example-hello-world.dox` with the following structure:

```
/*! \page  ex-page Example Program Page
 *
 *  \brief Example code for the "hello world" program.
 *
 *  \section ex-sec-description Program Details
 *
 *  In order to display the string "Hello World" to the standard output
 *  stream, the user should use the `std::cout` stream provided by C++.
 *
 *  \include example_hello_world.cpp
 *
 *  \section ex-sec-output Program Output
 *
 *  The program above will generate the following output when executed.
 *
 *            Hello World
 */
```